# Why is sprintf with possible buffer overflow allowed in Linux hwmon?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I've seen the following snippet of code used repeatedly for Linux hwmon devices:

```
return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", in_input);
```

Where `buf` is a pointer to char `char *buf`, and `in_input` usually an `int` or `u16`. The purpose is to copy the value read back from the device to the sysfs file created for this device attribute.

As an example, you can take a look at [Linux/drivers/hwmon/mcp3021.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/mcp3021.c) (or any hwmon device previous to 4.9 kernel really). You can see the function at line 81 returns a `u16`, and on line 99 the code stores the `u16` into the `char *buf`.

```
 81 static inline u16 volts_from_reg(struct mcp3021_data *data, u16 val)
 82 {
 83         return DIV_ROUND_CLOSEST(data->vdd * val, 1 << data->output_res);
 84 }
 85 
 86 static ssize_t show_in_input(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
 87                 char *buf)
 88 {
 89         struct i2c_client *client = to_i2c_client(dev);
 90         struct mcp3021_data *data = i2c_get_clientdata(client);
 91         int reg, in_input;
 92 
 93         reg = mcp3021_read16(client);
 94         if (reg < 0)
 95                 return reg;
 96 
 97         in_input = volts_from_reg(data, reg);
 98 
 99         return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", in_input);
100 }
```

Wouldn't this code always cause buffer overflow? We are always storing a u16 into a buffer allocated for char 8-bits. Why is this permitted in Linux device drivers?

Note that with my driver that does the exact same thing, sysfs displays the returned value correctly even though it cannot possibly be stored as a char (8-bits). So wondering if the `char *` representation is not accurate?

Comment: Question: is `snprintf()` available in kernel mode?

Comment: Good question, I certainly I can find it: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L411. But I don't see anyone in hwmon using it.

Comment: If the pointer in question points to a block of memory that is large enough then there's no problem.

Comment: "Wouldn't this code always cause buffer overflow?" no, why do you think so? If the caller passes a pointer to a buffer that is large enough there will be no buffer overflow.

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm I guess I've just never seen it done this way before. I always thought the size you allocate would be the size you pass in as the function parameter, meaning if you declare int buf, then your function should have parameter of int *buf. I've never seen it like this where potentially it's declared as (for example) int buf, but function parameter is a char *buf

Comment: @Splaty: Um.. But why do you claim that the code will "always produce buffer overflow"? Whether it will overflow depends on the actuall buffer size. And it is not visible in the code you posted. How do you know that the buffer is too small? What made you think so?

Comment: Check for NULL pointers before derefencing. (see audio-driver flaw)

Comment: @AnT My mistake. I thought that whatever argument passed in would be the allocated size of the block of memory. I see now that the actual block of memory and what is declared in the function parameter can be two different things.

Comment: `snprintf` is not a viable function for serious code. `snprintf` will truncate the output. In serious code truncated output is a no lesser problem that buffer overflow. Or it can be a "lesser" problem, but still unacceptable.

Comment: The parameter `char *buf` is a pointer to `char` -- but it's typically going to be a pointer to the initial element of an array of `char` objects. It's up to the caller to ensure that that array is long enough. In C, arrays are almost always manipulated via pointers to their elements (not pointers to the array as a whole). Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation in [sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt), the buffer passed to the `show` function is of size `PAGE_SIZE`:

> sysfs allocates a buffer of size (`PAGE_SIZE`) and passes it to the method. Sysfs will call the method exactly once for each read or write.

Since PAGE_SIZE is certainly bigger than the length of a small integer, there is no practical possibility of a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code shows poor programming style, but if `buf` is known to point to an array of at least 8 bytes, the behavior is defined and `sprintf` will not cause a buffer overflow.

Note that `show_in_input` does not receive the size of the destination buffer, the API would need to be changed for `snprintf()` to be used.

Comment: Thanks for explanation on why snprintf() is not used. When you say "buf is known to point to an array of at least 8 bytes" do you mean in reality, buf is actually bigger, but the API's function declaration of char * doesn't represent the full 8 bytes? Thus we can still take up the remaining 7 bytes without causing any harm?

Comment: @Splaty: "Actually bigger"? Actually bigger than *what*? `char *buf` declaration does not say anything at all about the actual buffer size.

Comment: @AnT Wait hold on, you lost me there. I always thought the function parameter, in this case char *buf, gives a sort of policy to say that buffer size is 8 bits. We don't know the actual buffer size but isn't the function parameter a sort of contract for the code implementing this callback?

Comment: @Splaty: Not really. `char *buf` is just a pointer that points to the begining of some buffer (or unknown size). That buffer can be arbutrarily large. Apparently, these functions *require* the caller to supply a buffer that is sufficiently large to store an ASCII representation of an `int` - that's the external contract in this case.

Comment: @AnT Oh ok. Hmm... then out of curiousity I wonder why the kernel developers who made the function parameters would use char *buf rather than int *buf. Wouldn't that be a more proper representation?

Comment: @Splaty: Um... I don't get your point. The buffer is supposed to be used as a *string*. In C a string is a sequence of `char`s. That's why it is `char *`. How would `int *` fit in here is completely unclear to me.

Comment: @AnT I understand now. Thanks.